# Where does vagrant store logs?

Tags: windows, logging, vagrant

I am trying to do a little debugging as to why my vagrant box is throwing errors when I do `vagrant up`.

On windows I have:

```
$ set VAGRANT_LOG=info 
$ vagrant up
```

Where does vagrant store the log file?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250011/13011

Comment: 'export VAGRANT_LOG=info' worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Virtual Box provider, the logs are stored at `~/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_box_name/Logs`.

There is a VBox.log and a VBoxStartup.log.

I think @balintant is right too, as these are not 'vagrant' logs, but Virtual Box logs (which is what I was really looking for).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know vagrant does not write into logfiles, it only has output to stdout.

*PS.: I Googled it and found nothing - even in the Vagrant documentations -, so I think I am right.*

Comment: Yes I think you are right, as they also output please check the log ABOVE to find what went wrong. So everything they log is to stdout.

Comment: Please check the right answer below. It _does_ store file.

Comment: @jjmerelo Vagrant does not. Virtual Box does (see accepted answer), but that's not what the OP asked. So you can use "tee" as in the other answer to redirect stdout also to a file.

Answer (score 3):

I work with Vagrant on a POSIX OS (Mac/Linux) but I was able to find Windows PowerShell equivalent(?) commands. I don't work in Windows so you'll have to test these things yourself.

Within the current working directory (I just happen to be experimenting with CoreOS at the moment):

List the contents of your directory; Linux:

```
$ ll
...
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myAcct myGroup 3.3K Nov 22 15:33 config.rb
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myAcct myGroup 1.3K Nov 22 16:43 vagrant-info.out
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myAcct myGroup 1.1K Nov 22 16:42 myAcct-data
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myAcct myGroup 4.6K Nov 22 16:05 Vagrantfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myAcct myGroup  306 Nov 22 16:47 vagrant.env
```

Windows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force C:\dir\path
```

I use the vagrant.env file to record/use/reuse experiment-specific environment variables. It looks like this; Linux:

```
$ cat vagrant.env 
# Environment Variables on a per-experiment basis
# Name a non-default Vagrant Provider:
#export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER='vmware_fusion'
# Which CoreOS channel
export channel='channel=stable'
# Set a log level for troubleshooting: debug or info
export VAGRANT_LOG='info'
#export VAGRANT_DEBUG_LAUNCHER
```

Windows: (I belive [type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.12.powershell.aspx) is as close as you can get)

```
C:\> type vagrant.env
```

These variables can then be introduced into the environment; Linux:

```
source vagrant.env
```

Windows:

```
. .\vagrant.env
```

After that, start Vagrant; Linux:

```
vagrant up | tee -ai vagrant-log-info.out
```

On Windows the [Tee-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx) might work like this:

```
vagrant up  | Tee-Object -file vagrant-log-info.out
```

On Linux, this method will drop a log named (something meaningful): vagrant-log-info.out

I can then read that log, save it for posterity or whatever. I hope this helps.

Please feel free to update this with tested versions of these commands. I can imagine it must be a fairly common need.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/debugging.html says:

```
unix# VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up >vagrant.log
unix# VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up | tee vagrant.log

power-shell> vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log
power-shell> vagrant up --debug | Tee-Object -FilePath ".\vagrant.log"
```

So there is no specific file location, only STDOUT.